# Prove that $f$ is periodic if and only if $f(a) =f(0)$.

Tags: calculus

> Suppose that $f'$ is periodic with period $a$. Prove that $f$ is periodic if and only if $f(a) =f(0)$.

I understand the direction assuming that $f(a) = f(0)$, but the other direction I don't get in the solution below. How do they get $f(na) = nf(a) - (n-1)f(0) = \dfrac{n}{n+1}[(n-1)f(a)-f(0)]$?

The following is the solution the book gives for the second part:

> Conversely, suppose that $f$ is periodic (with some period not necessarily equal to $a$).  Let $g(x)=f(x+a)-f(x)$.  Then $g'(x)=f'(x+a)-f'(x)=0$, so $g$ has the constant value $g(0)=f(a)-f(0)$.  I.e., $$f(x+a)=f(x)+f(a)-f(0)$$  It follows that $$f(na)=nf(a)-(n-1)f(0)=\frac{n}{n+1}[(n-1)f(a)-f(0)]$$  Now if $f(a)\neq f(0)$, then this would be unbounded.  But $f$ is bounded since it is periodic.

Comment: Have you considered induction?

Comment: Did you understand how they got f(x+a) = f(x) + f(a) - f(0)?

Comment: It seems that the converse is most easily proven by contradiction. assume f (x) =  0 and x is not a multiple of a.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, that follows since $f(x+a) = f(x)+g(x) = f(x)+f(a)-f(0)$.

Comment: if $f(a)-f(0) = c$ (that is $f(2a) = c + f(0)$) then $f(2a)-f(a) = c$ and so $f(2a) = 2c + f(0)$, etc, etc.

Comment: If so the f(na) = f(na - a) + f(a) - f(0) = f(na-2a) + 2f(a)-2f(0)=f(na-3a) + 3f(a) - 3f(0)=.....  =f(na - (n-1)a) + (n-1)f(a) - (n-1)f(0) = f(a) + (n-1)f(a) - (n-1)f(0) = nf(a) - (n-1)f(0).

Comment: It follows by induction:  f(na) = f(a+a+a+a......+a) = f(a+a+a....+a) + f(a) - f(0) = f(a+a...+a) + 2f(a) - 2f(0)=.....= f(a) + (n-1)f(a) - (n-1)f(0)

Comment: How do we know that f is bounded? A function which is periodic need not be bounded, e.g. $tanx$.

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy induction problem.

If you are not familiar with induction:
\begin{align}
f(2a)&=f(a+a)=2f(a)-f(0) \\
f(3a)&=f(2a+a)=f(2a)+f(a)-f(0) \\
f(4a)&=f(3a+a)=f(3a)+f(a)-f(0) \\
\vdots& \\
f(na)&=f((n-1)a)+f(a)-f(0)\end{align}

Add all these relations and cancel $f(2a), f(3a),.., f((n-1)a)$. You get
$$f(na)=nf(a)-(n-1)f(0)=(n-1)\left( \frac{n}{n-1}f(a) -f(0) \right)$$

Now, if $f(a) \neq f(0)$, $(n-1)$ goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$,

Comment: @Bungo TY, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Slightly differently worded:
As $g$ is constant, we have $f(x+a)-f(x)=g(x)=g(0)$ for all $x$, hence $f(na)=f(0)+ng(0)$ by induction on $n$. If $g(0)\ne 0$, this is unbounded, whereas a continuous periodic function must be bounded. Hence we conclude $g\equiv 0$, i.e., $f(x+a)=f(x)$ for all $x$.