# Average of periodic functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functions, periodic-functions

A function $f$ is periodic if there exists $T \neq 0$ (a period) such that $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for all $x$. Let $f$ be a periodic function with fundamental period $T$ (that is, $T$ is the lowest positive period, supposing that one such exists). Suppose that $f$ is bounded and integrable on the interval $[0, T]$.
in the previous theorem we have proved that:

$$ \lim\limits_{\vert{y}\vert\to\infty}\frac{1}{y}\int_0^yf=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf$$

The quantity $$\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf$$  we will call mean of the periodic function

**Exercise**:

Let $$F(x)=\int_0^xf$$ Show that $F$ is periodic if and only if $f$ has mean zero.

**My approach**:

First suppose that $F$ is periodic function with the lowest positive period $a$.

Then $$F(x)=F(x+a)$$

$$\int_0^xf(u)\,d(u)=\int_0^{x+a}f(u)\,d(u)=\int_0^af(u)\,d(u)+\int_a^{a+x}f(u)\,d(u)$$

Since $$\int_a^{a+x}f(u)\,d(u)=\int_0^xf(u)\,d(u)$$ it implies that $$\int_0^af(u)\,d(u)=0$$

Second:

Assume that: $$\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf=0$$

$$F(x+T)=\int_0^{x+T}f(u)\,d(u)=\int_0^Tf(u)\,d(u)+\int_T^{T+x}f(u)\,d(u)=\int_0^Tf(u)\,d(u)+\int_0^xf(u+T)\,d(u)=\int_0^Tf(u)\,d(u)+\int_0^xf(u)\,d(u)=\int_0^xf(u)\,d(u)=F(x)$$

Please, can anybody check this proof??

Comment: In the second part, $f$ is also assumed to be periodic? Do not cut the interval at $x$, cut it at the full period $T$.

Comment: yes, f is periodic we need to proof F to be periodic

Comment: sorry about cutting I didn't understand

Comment: aaaa yeah thanks a lot @LutzLehmann I got it. I will change

Comment: For this to work, you also need to show that $a$, the period of $F$, is some whole number multiple of $T$, the period of $f$.

Comment: yes @eyeballfrog thank you, I recognized it short a time ago,After all, their period may be different. even I think their lowest positive period should be the same??

Comment: I think I could construct second part properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copying the answer of @ N. S. to the similar question in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790964/prove-that-f-is-periodic-if-and-only-if-fa-f0)

\begin{align}
F(2T)&=F(T+T)=2F(T)-F(0) \\
F(3T)&=F(2T+T)=F(2T)+F(T)-f(0) \\
F(4T)&=F(3T+T)=F(3T)+F(T)-f(0) \\
\vdots& \\
F(nT)&=F((n-1)T)+F(T)-F(0)\end{align}

Add all these relations and cancel $F(2T), F(3T),.., F((n-1)T)$. You get
$$F(nT)=nF(T)-(n-1)F(0)=(n-1)\left( \frac{n}{n-1}F(T)-F(0) \right)$$
Now, if $F(T) \neq F(0)$ the last bracket goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$

Now if $F(a)≠F(0)$, then this would be unbounded. But F is bounded since it is continuous periodic function.

Comment: \bib\{1790968}{misc}{    
    title={Prove that $f$ is periodic if and only if $f(a) =f(0)$.},    
    author={N. S. (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9176/n-s)},    
    note={URL: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1790968 (version: 2016-05-18)},    
    eprint={https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1790968},    
    organization={Mathematics Stack Exchange}  
}